# Are there any downsides of creating TensorFlow placeholders for variable sized vs. fixed sized inputs?

Tags: tensorflow

I am wondering is there are any substantial downsides (e.g., regarding computational efficiency, memory...) in creating TensorFlow placeholders for variable sized inputs (vs. fixed sized inputs)?

Say, I am doing mini-batch learning and initialize the graph with a placeholder where I assume a fixed batch_size upfront:

```
tf.placeholder(..., shape=[batch_size, ...])
```

Alternatively, I can initialize the placeholder variable so that it accepts variable sized inputs:

```
tf.placeholder(..., shape=[None, ...])
```

I am not that familiar with the low level tensorflow implementations under the hood, but wouldn't the latter have to check dimensions, allocate memory, and create new arrays at each iteration to account for a case where my minibatch size changes during training? So, depending on the implementation, wouldn't that be computationally wasteful if I am working with a fixed batch dimension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a definite tension between providing fully defined shapes (which can yield better performance) and allowing dimensions to vary (which makes the dataflow graph easier to reuse). As you suspect, there are some downsides to using variable-shaped [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) ops to represent input in a TensorFlow model:

- TensorFlow is often able to simplify the dataflow graph when shapes are fully known. For example, a call to [`tf.shape(x)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) returns a `tf.Tensor` containing the true dynamic shape of a tensor `x`. If that shape is fully defined at graph construction time, TensorFlow will replace the shape computation with a [`tf.constant()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant), and this will be used in constant folding optimizations to reduce the amount of work done at runtime.
- As an extreme case, the [XLA compiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/experimental/xla/) requires that all input tensor shapes be fully defined before code is generated, so that it can generate much more efficient kernel code where array bounds (etc.) are compile-time constants. XLA recompiles the kernel code for each combination of input shapes, so using fixed-size tensors will avoid the recompilation overhead.
- TensorFlow's memory allocator currently *does* allocate new arrays for every intermediate and output tensor at each call to `tf.Session.run()`. However, the underlying memory allocators (the BFC allocator for GPU memory, and `tcmalloc` or `jemalloc` for CPU memory) tend to perform better if they have a static distribution of allocation requests (since the requests can be satisfied from buffers that were recently freed).

Comment: thanks for this nice and comprehensive explanation! So, for large (long -to-train) models it would probably be more efficient then to fix the batch size. However, for validation and evaluation (validation and test sets), one would have to have a parallel graph that would be fed with the training graph's variables, which could outweigh the advantages.

Comment: That's probably true. It's tricky to be definitive about the relative performance, but we've seen as much as a 5% running time improvements from using static shape information, so if you have a long-running program it is probably worthwhile to use separate programs for training/eval with as much static information as possible.

Comment: On a similar note, should there be a performance difference between creating a `tf.constant` and creating a `tf.placeholder` of constant shape + passing its value at graph evaluation time ?

Comment: It would be interesting if it were possible to not specify the exact `batch_size` but instead the maximum value it can take and then it could infer the true size of the batch on any data passed in. 

This way it wouldn't require a lot of allocing and de-allocing of memory (as we know the maximum size arrays we need so they only need to be aloocated one) but also would also maintain performance gains on batches whose size is much less than the maximum batch size.

Comment: So you've only "seen as much as a 5% running time improvements from using static shape information"?  That's good to know, because although it might for some people, 5% doesn't make a difference to me. I just want to make sure that using variable batch sizes doesn't make it +20% slower.