# How to calculate class scores when batch size changes

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, tensorflow

My question is at the bottom, but first I will explain what I am attempting to achieve.

I have an example I am trying to implement on my own model. I am creating an adversarial image, in essence I want to graph how the image score changes when the epsilon value changes.

So let's say my `model` has already been trained, and in this example I am using the following model...

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])

...
...

# construct model
logits = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)  # Softmax
```

Next, let us assume I extract an array of images of the number 2 from the `mnist` data set, and I saved it in the following variable...

```
# convert into a numpy array of shape [100, 784]
labels_of_2 = np.concatenate(labels_of_2, axis=0)
```

So now, in the example that I have, the next step is to try different epsilon values on every image...

```
# random epsilon values from -1.0 to 1.0
epsilon_res = 101
eps = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, epsilon_res).reshape((epsilon_res, 1))
labels = [str(i) for i in range(10)]

num_colors = 10
cmap = plt.get_cmap('hsv')
colors = [cmap(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, num_colors)]


# Create an empty array for our scores
scores = np.zeros((len(eps), 10))

for j in range(len(labels_of_2)):

   # Pick the image for this iteration
   x00 = labels_of_2[j].reshape((1, 784))

    # Calculate the sign of the derivative,
    # at the image and at the desired class
    # label
    sign = np.sign(im_derivative[j])

     # Calculate the new scores for each
     # adversarial image 
     for i in range(len(eps)):
        x_fool = x00 + eps[i] * sign
        scores[i, :] = logits.eval({x: x_fool, 
                                keep_prob: 1.0})
```

Now we can graph the images using the following...

```
# Create a figure
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
plt.title("Image {}".format(j))

# Loop through the score functions for each
# class label and plot them as a function of
# epsilon
for k in range(len(scores.T)):
    plt.plot(eps, scores[:, k], 
             color=colors[k], 
             marker='.', 
             label=labels[k])

plt.legend(prop={'size':8})
plt.xlabel('Epsilon')
plt.ylabel('Class Score')
plt.grid('on')
```

For the first image the graph would look something like the following...

[image]

**Now Here Is My Question**

Let's say the model I trained used a `batch_size` of `100`, in that case the following line would not work...

```
 scores[i, :] = logits.eval({x: x_fool, 
                                keep_prob: 1.0})
```

In order for this to work, I would need to pass an array of 100 images to the model, but in this instance `x_fool` is just one image of size `(1, 784)`.

I want to graph the effect of different epsilon values on class scores for any one image, but how can I do so when I need calculate the score of `100` images at a time (since my model was trained on a batch_size of 100)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to not choose a batch size by setting it to `None`. That way, any batch size can be used.

However, keep in mind that this non-choice could com with [a moderate penalty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547456/are-there-any-downsides-of-creating-tensorflow-placeholders-for-variable-sized-v).

This fixes it if you start again from scratch. If you start from an existing trained network with a batch size of 100, you can create a test network that is similar to your starting network except for the batch size. You can set the batch size to `1`, or again, to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I realised the problem was not with the `batch_size` but with the format of the image I was attempting to pass to the model. As *user1735003* pointed out, the `batch_size` does not matter.

The reason I could not pass the image to the model was because I was passing it as so...

```
x_fool = x00 + eps[i] * sign
scores[i, :] = logits.eval({x: x_fool})
```

The problem with this is that the shape of the image is simply `(784,)` whereas the placeholder needs to accept an array of images of shape `shape=[None, 784]`, so what needs to be done is to `reshape` the image.

```
x_fool = labels_of_2[0].reshape((1, 784)) + eps[i] * sign
scores[i, :] = logits.eval({x:x_fool})
```

Now my image is shape `(1, 784)` which can now be accepted by the placeholder.