# Tensorflow placeholder shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow, we specify a placeholder as, say:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 64, 64, 3))
```

to indicate unknown number of batches of 64x64x3 images.

Sometimes we don't know the dimensions of the placeholder, and we can just say:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
```

**What are advantages and disadvantages of specifying shapes whenever we can?**

E.g. are there performance gains, is it only for defensive programming (throw errors when feeded arrays have wrong dims), etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this was already answered in this question: [Are there any downsides of creating TensorFlow placeholders for variable sized vs. fixed sized inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547456/are-there-any-downsides-of-creating-tensorflow-placeholders-for-variable-sized-v).

But in summary: for efficiency and debugging reasons, you probably want to specify the shapes whenever you can. The disadvantage is that your code probably will not be so reusable.